# Alternative to Hidden Field in HTML

Tags: html, outlook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternatives to Hidden Field in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244775/alternatives-to-hidden-field-in-html)

I am using a hidden field to hide some fields when i send an email which are confidential. When i am sending the email which contains the hidden field embedded into it, I am able to retrieve the hidden fields using Java.  My problem is that, when i forward the same email the hidden fields are missing in the HTML. This case also applies to bounced emails. My requirement is to extract those hidden fiels values from a bounced email. I want to know if there is any alternative to hidden fields or how to accomplish the task using hidden fields.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

---

The Issue I have is not about confidential data, Its about the Information. Say for example, as you said, i send email with Unique ID in it as hidden while sending email. but the same unique id seems to have disappeared from html, once i forward that email or in the bounced email. In short  tag of type hidden is getting disappeared after sending the email. Any info on this would be of great help.

Comment: Protip: don't use hidden fields to store confidential information. Anyone with minimal technical skills can bring the information up with almost no effort at all.

Comment: check this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085993/php-alternative-to-html-hidden-input]

Answer (score 3):

Even if you hide a field in HTML, users can still see the information by looking at the html source. **Do not hide confidential data in HTML hidden fields or comments! It is not secure!**

The most secure way to remember some data through an email, is to save the data to a private database, and create a unique random key to represent the data. Then you can just include the unique key in the email you send.

To get the data back when you receive the email bounce, just look up the unique key in your database, and you have the information back.

Anybody else receiving that email will not be able to see the private and confidential data.