# Getting value from the fields in same parent div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and I have almost 5 divs in a page and all of them have same ids as generated by php. I have a button and an anchor tag. Both of them will call same jQuery function when clicked.

```
/*This div is in foreach*/
<div id="rev">

/*Here are 2 input fields*/
<input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $this->session->user_data('user_id'); ?>" />

<p id="total_rev"><?php echo $value['total_review']; ?> Reviews</p>
<input type="button" id="write_review" value="Write a review..." />
</div>
```

Problem starts here :
I am having 2 hidden inputs as I have to fetch user_id and product_id in the jQuery function. Both inputs are child of the same parent div as of the button and anchor. But across all page there is same post 5 times and all posts have different user_id and product_id.

I am new to jQuery. Just wanted to know how can I fetch the user_id and product_id related to the same div of which the button was clicked.

```
$('document').ready(function() {
$('#write_review').click(function() {
    var product_id, user_id;
    var hidden_elemets = $(this).parent().siblings('input:hidden');
    $(hidden_elemets).map(function(){
        if($(this).name == 'res_id')
            alert(this.value);
    });
});
});
```

This is the JQuery function that i have till far

Is there any other way than using hidden inputs? Please enlighten!

I hope you understand my question!

Comment: Can you post your code too, that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `parent()` at all. Just stick with `siblings()`. Look at your HTML content:

```
<div id="rev"> <!-- The parent element -->
    <input type="hidden" /> <------
    <input type="hidden" />       |
                                  | These are all siblings of each other
    <p id="total_rev"></p>        |
    <input type="button" /> <------
</div>
```

When you get the `parent()` and then `siblings()` of that, you are going back up to the parent `#rev` and then searching back down again through IT'S siblings, not the event handler's siblings.

Just use `siblings()` of `#write-review`:

```
var $this = $(this),
    product_id = $this.siblings('#product_id').val(),
    user_id = $this.siblings('#user_id').val(),
    hidden_elements = $this.siblings('input:hidden');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzd6B/)

As far as there being an alternative to hidden inputs? No not really. As deceze says in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085993/php-alternative-to-html-hidden-input):

> Hidden HTML inputs shouldn't cause any security problems though, *as long as you properly validate them (again) before putting them in the database.*

Comment: Woah! Finally got what i was doing wrong. Thanks for explaining! :)

Answer (score 1):

I usually either use `.parent()` or `.closest(:selector)`

Here's a jsfiddle that demonstrates both

http://jsfiddle.net/xBfvp/